# What is the best way to center images in websites?

Tags: css, image, html

Every time I work on a new project I do not have any problems to center the text using "text-align: center" to center the text, but I have never seen a similar code to center images so I always have hack the code by either centering the images in the HTML (not the cleanest option) or by giving the image a variable width (which does not work on multiple resolutions). Is there any way to accomplish this that I have not tried? And, does any one know if something like this will be implemented in CSS3?

Comment: I dont think so but what I do Is in my HTML file I will add: `<center><img src="example.png"/></center>`

Comment: I think this belongs on DocType.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the containing elements style to

```
text-align:center;
```

set your image style  to

```
display:inline-block;
margin:auto;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sruly's answer hits the nail on the head.
the only thing I would consider adding is `vertical-align: middle;` for the image tag, as follows:

```
display:inline-block;
margin:auto;
vertical-align: middle;
```